# OG view-content

Tags: forms, organic-groups

Can somebody tell me, how can i restrict viewing a certain-content type in an OG group to only group admin, so no other group members can see it.

And the 2nd question, if anibody knows; you can assign a field called group_audience. Is there an option, to not actually show the field, but assign a value of whatever group the user is in. Can I do this using hook_form_alter?

Answer (score 1):

In your og node template you can use conditional php to show certain content.

```
<?php if (og_is_node_admin($group)):?>

 // Put whatever fields that you want viewable by the admin only

<?php endif;?>
```

Comment: So there is no module that would limit access for viewing the content?

Comment: The various content access modules would give you the ability to limit access for viewing specific fields and content types, but your assigning those permissions per role. I guess you could create a rule that adds a role to that use if they are a group admin, and then assign the appropriate content access permissions, but that seems like a lot of work compared to my answer.

Answer (score 0):

> Question #2: if anibody knows; you can assign a field called group_audience. Is there an option, to not actually show the field, but assign a value of whatever group the user is in. Can I do this using hook_form_alter?

Check out [this comment](http://drupal.org/node/1018624#comment-5026648). It shows you how to create a module that will do that.